# Using Javascript's range feature to pull from Google Sheets

Tags: javascript

I'm using Google Sheets/Script, and I'm trying to pull a range of cells without directly imputing the range.

For example, I know the correct notation to get and work with a range is:

```
var range = sheet.getRange('A1:B3');
```

Buuut, I'm trying to get my program to pull a range based off a date in another cell. I'll probably use a loop to do so.

It would be much easier if there were a way to put a level of distance between the "getrange" class notation and the ranges I need to pull. For instance, below I put X to be my range then put X into ".getRange()". Works good!

```
  var x = 'A1:B3';
  var range = sheet.getRange(x);
```

However, I need to be able to changed x based on the loop, so I tried:

```
 var y = 'F1',
      z = 'I2',
      x = y:z;
  var range = sheet.getRange(x);
```

I wasn't quite expecting that to work because the notation has to be correct, but I can't seem to create an X that will use Y and Z and create a usable X for my getRange.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do this: `x = y+':'+z;`

Comment: `x = y + ":" + z`?

Comment: x = y + ':' + z; works! Thanks!

Comment: @KayZak I posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ES6 and above, use [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
var y = 'F1',
    z = 'I2',
    x = `${y}:${z}`;
```

Older versions of JavaScript:

```
var y = 'F1',
    z = 'I2',
    x = y + ':' + z;
```